# React Redux Firebase Hooks: useSelector doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

```
function FlashcardScreen() {
  useFirestoreConnect('flashcards')
  const projects = useSelector(state => {
    state.firestore.data.flashcards 
  })
  console.log(projects)

  return(// some ui element)
}
```

My Question is when I console.log(state.firestore.data.flashcards) I get my data. But when I console.log(projects) I don't get it. Why? And does it have anything to do with redux-thunk?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work, the arrow function in the selector should return some value e.g.

```
  const projects = useSelector(state => {
     return state.firestore.data.flashcards 
  })
```

Or simply remove the curly brackets

```
const projects = useSelector(state => state.firestore.data.flashcards)
```